# Connect SQL 2008 with SQL 2005 SSMS

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008

i need to connect SQL Server 2008 instance with SQL Server 2005 Management Studio. There is a limitation on my Box that i can not upgrade the framework to 3.5. There are few applications running on my box which will stop functioning after 3.5 upgrade. Is there any way to achieve this? I GOOGLE this problem and found a Cumulative update package for this problem. i installed this too but there is no hope so far.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/943656

I would be very grateful if someone can help me out in this regard.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Can you not remote desktop to the box hosting the SQL 2008 instance and use the tools installed locally.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes, i am using right now the Remote Desktop connection to use this 2008 instance. But without license i can only create 2 Remote connections to that machine which is insufficient for me.

Regards